# Manipulating and Removing Facets in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, facet

I am creating a front end application which queries through a database using the Apache Solr engine, but I have two issues that I just cannot find the answer to.

When Solr is processing a Facet query, how do I get the facet to be a single phrase ("Department of the Navy (160)") instead of a broken up facet of 4 terms ("Department (160)" "of (200)" "the (200)" "Navy(160)").

Also, how do I remove certain facets from being queried, for example "and" "to" "the" etc.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of the phrase, and how were you indexing?

Comment: @Ramzy The data type of the phrase was text, but I just made a duplicate field in the schema.xml file and made it of type string instead of text and it picked up the entire field without slicing it up.
Got it working now!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your phrase is being indexed into a Text field which, among many things, splits by whitespace. This is very good for full text search but not for faceting.

You can have a duplicate field for this, of type string (and not Text), which is not splitted. You can still use the original field for searching but the new string field for faceting.

Comment: I wanna kiss you Fermin.
I added a <copy field> to my schema.xml and added a duplicate field, but made it a string instead of text and it worked like a charm.